# Cookie creating URL behaves different inside PHP CURL code

Tags: php, curl, cookies

i have used the below url to set cookies in my browser

```
http://localhost/setc.php?userid=123&panelid=1
```

now i have used php curl to do it(writing the code inside another script), but it does not work(doesnot set a cookie) at the moment

can any expert of this, spot what is the error with my code using curl

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/setc.php?userid=123&panelid=1');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "Cookie saved");
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

and let me know where to edit in this